Counterexample for unitary isometry when $\dim(\mathcal{H})=\infty$
Exercise 2.1 of https://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/IMP2018final.pdf goes as follows:

Let $u\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Show that:
$\bullet$ $u$ is an isometry iff $\left\Vert u\psi\right\Vert^{2}=\left\Vert \psi\right\Vert ^{2}$ for each $\psi\in\mathcal{H}$.
$\bullet$ $u$ is unitary iff it is an invertible partial isometry,
or,equivalently, a surjective isometry (in particular, an isometry is
automatically injective).
$\bullet$ If $\dim(\mathcal{H})<\infty$, then an isometry is automatically
unitary (and give a counterexample to this if
$\dim(\mathcal{H})=\infty$).

What I would like to understand is the counterexample of $\dim(\mathcal{H})=\infty$, as mentioned in the last part. Can anyone provide an example or better reference?

The unilateral shift $s$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is the standard example. It is defined by $s(e_n) = e_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Shift operators are standard counterexamples to keep in mind about theorems from linear algebra that break in infinite dimensions

@DavidGao Can you please elaborate a little? from what I know, if the translation operation is unitary than it can be written as $exp(iO)$ where $O$ is a self-adjoint operator. So this will fail to be the case in your example?

The shift operator is not a unitary, but it is an isometry. That’s the point here. It is the kind of counterexample the question asked for, no?

Any $\exp(iO)$ where $O$ is self-adjoint is a unitary and any unitary can be written in that form. So as the shift operator is not a unitary, it cannot be written as such.

@DavidGao Thanks. Just to conclude - the shift operator is unitary (and therefore, can be written as $exp(iO)$ with $O$ self-adjoint) on a finite dimensional space, but when the space is infinity dimensional this breaks down. Do you have any other interesting examples?

There isn’t really a shift operator as such on a finite-dimensional space. After all, the definition is $s(e_n) = e_{n+1}$. If the dimension of the space is $d$, then $s(e_d)$ is supposed to be $e_{d+1}$, but there is no $e_{d+1}$. The closest one has is to require $s(e_d) = e_1$. That would result in a unitary operator on the $d$-dimensional space, but usually it just wouldn’t be called the shift operator. (And yes, in that case it can be written as $\exp(iO)$, as it is a unitary in that case.)

In a sense, there isn’t really any other example. There is a result (Wold–von Neumann decomposition) that says any isometry on a Hilbert space is a direct sum of copies of the shift operator (also called the unilateral shift, to differentiate with the bilateral shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$) and a unitary. Effectively the “non-unitary” part of an isometry all comes from this shift operator.

@DavidGao At least in my general point of view, and please let me know if I'm wrong here, this subtlety is generated since element 'infinity' is not a part of the real numbers. When working with real numbers $\left[\exp(iO)\right]^{*}\exp(iO)=\exp(-iO)\exp(iO)=1$. But the last two transitions will no longer be valid if $O=\infty$.

I, uh, suppose that is one way to look at it? Personally I don’t think that’s much relevant, but if it helps your understanding then that’s that. Slightly more formally, the construction of $O$ requires normality and the spectrum being contained in the unit circle, neither of which is true for an isometry that is not a unitary. As for why such phenomena can only happen in infinite dimensions, I think the better analogy is the fact that between finite sets, an injective function is automatically surjective, whereas there are injective but not surjective functions on infinite sets.

@DavidGao Great! Thank you!

The first examples anybody should be exposed to when they start learning about infinite-dimensional linear algebra are the following. Let $V$ be the vector space of "infinite vectors," or sequences $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots )$ (we could also take sequences with finite support, it doesn't matter too much). Consider on $V$ the following linear operators $V \to V$, namely the right shift
$$R(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots) = (0, a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots )$$
and the left shift
$$L(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots ) = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots ).$$
Check the following, all of which are impossible if $V$ is finite-dimensional:

$R$ is injective but not surjective. Hence it embeds $V$ nontrivially into itself.
$L$ is surjective but not injective. Hence it exhibits $V$ as a nontrivial quotient of itself.
$R$ has no eigenvectors, even over an algebraically closed field, hence no eigenvalues.
The only eigenvalue of $L$ is $0$, but $L$ is not nilpotent.
$LR = 1$, but $RL(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots) = (0, a_1, a_2, \dots)$. $L$ is right invertible but not left invertible, $R$ is left invertible but not right invertible, and $LR = 1$ does not imply $RL = 1$.

This example can be converted into a Hilbert space example by modifying $V$ to be $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. In this case, as David says in the comments, $R$ is an isometry but not unitary because it is not surjective, and $L = R^{\dagger}$ is its adjoint. It remains true that $R$ has no eigenvectors; this shows that we can't define the spectrum using eigenvalues alone.

@Yair: well, the position operator isn't an isometry, so it isn't relevant to the question you asked. It is unbounded, which makes things more complicated in a way I'm not familiar with.

Thanks, I see your point.
